# Joining a queried table to a feature class

Tags: arcgis-desktop, attribute-joins, table, definition-query

I have a table in a geodatabase that I would like to join to a feature class. The table contains well locations with multiple sample dates and associated data, however, I am only interested in sample events that occurred in August. I applied a definition query to the table, but when I tried to join it to the feature class it failed. I removed the definition query and tried to join again and it was successful, but joined the data was based on the earliest sample event (February). I am working with ArcGIS Desktop v10.3. Is it possible to apply a definition query to a table and join it to a feature class?

Comment: Related: [Add Join not keeping all target features](https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-pro-questions/add-join-not-keeping-all-target-features/td-p/1341474/highlight/true).

Answer (score 1):

1. apply the query to the table and export selected results
2. join the new exported table with desired attributes to Feature Class.
3. Export the feature class with the join to a new Feature Class.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but one of the reasons I am interested in using a definition query before joining is to reduce the number of tables needed to be created. Instead of creating individual tables for each sampling event, I'd like to be able to query which sampling events I'm interested in from one table.